# Is this power source switching circuit design correct?

Tags: circuit-analysis, batteries, diodes, battery-charging

I'm making a circuit which will allow the device to switch between battery and external power source.

When connected to wall outlet, it should power the device and charge the battery.
The battery in question is a 3s2p lithium ion battery with a common port BMS.

I've made the circuit on a prototype board, and was checking it with a multimeter.

**When I connect 12V 2A adapter to emulate battery discharge, and there's no adapters connected, I'm seeing ~3V and ~6V at V1 and V2 resp.** Why is this happening? Shouldn't it be 0V?

*Why did I add two power sources?*

The device consumes about 20W, and I want to charge the battery at around 24W. Since I only have 12V 2A adapters lying around, I wanted to build a circuit accordingly.
I've added schottky diodes at each source to ensure one source is not feeding off another.

If this is wrong way to do it, please let me know.
If there are any mistakes in circuit design, please let me know.
Thank you!

The circuit:
[image]

The battery. The cable with female barrel connecter is used as charging cable:
[image]

Edit:
[image]

Comment: 1: I'm not sure what that device in the center of your schematic is; a transistor?

2: Reverse leakage current of a 1N5817 at 25C with 12V applied is 0.25mA, which is probably the source of your voltage reading.

3: Paralleling diodes isn't a simple adding of their currents and even if it were, running devices for long periods at their limit isn't usually advisable.  I suggest a single diode with a DC current rating of at least 3A.

Comment: That device is the li-ion battery with the two cables. I wanted to emphasize that adapters aren't connected with both cables. Apologies for wrong diagram.
Thanks for telling me abot the leakage current, missed it out! Would 1N5408 be a proper component for the purpose?

Comment: The current rating and power handling on the 1N5408 are fine, but the voltage drop is a relatively extravagant 1.1V.  You might want to look into using one of the barrel connector jacks with a built in switch.

Comment: You are right, the voltage drop would be quite high, I am not sure if this is a good implementation. While I can't use the switched jack, because the charger would be connected via a dock like in a roomba, I was thinking to sense voltage and feed it to a microcontroller, and based on this input trigger relays to switch to external power source and charge battery. I've added the image in the post.

I'm using a buck converter for my device, which gives a regulated 5V. Will that take care of any spikes or bouncing which can occur during the switch? Or do I need to design for it in the circuit?

Comment: I will be using 100k resistor to ensure current flowing into the microcontroller is low and within the acceptable range

Comment: I don't want to go too far since I don't know too much about the battery, but maybe just use a different bare battery and use a charge controller with parallel load capability?  They're maybe $5 altogether.